# Conservation law for generic linear hyperbolic PDEs?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, hyperbolic-pde, conservation-laws

Consider the wave equation:

$$
u_{tt} = \Delta u, \text{ on }U\times [0,T], u=0\text{ on }\partial U\times[0,T].
$$

To prove the only solution for the zero initial condition is zero, we only need to prove that the energy $E = \int_U |u_t|^2 + |\nabla u|^2 dx$ is conserved. We only need $\frac{dE}{dt}\leq 0.$

However, the several proof I see for the uniqueness of general parabolic equations
$$
u_{tt} = L u
$$
where $L$ is a uniformly elliptic differential operator, all use the a Grönwall's inequality style argument. Is there a way to do it through an energy $E$ such that $\frac{dE}{dt}\leq 0$ instead?

Comment: I do not think you need Gronwall if $L$ is in divergence form with coefficients independent of $t$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune That looks impressive. I have a proof which does not use Gronwall, but have $\exp$ all over the place.